# Listing all articles on Wikitravel.org (excluding redirects)

Tags: wiki, url

Here is the list of all articles on the excellent guide [Wikitravel.org](http://wikitravel.org/):

http://wikitravel.org/en/Special:Allpages/A1GP

**PROBLEM:** It also includes [redirects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aRedirect).
For each real article there are tens of redirects, so the list linked above is unusable.

I could click each link to check whether it is a redirect or not, but that would hit their server too hard, or take weeks.

**QUESTION:** Is there an URL option or other trick, to filter out redirect pages?

*For the curious: Wikitravel's data is copyleft, but they do not provide database dumps.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in the list of all articles (linked above), each link to a redirect is in a `<div class="allpagesredirect"> ... </div>` tag.

That makes it easy to filter out redirects.